# Setting javascript variable value from Pop-Up window to the parent using window.opener or something else

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML page (Lets call this Parent Page), from where a new Pop-Up (Child Page) can be opened by clicking on a link. But I am in situation to set the **Parent page's** javascript variable by using the javascript processing on this pop-up page.

I tried using window.opener but it results into error **`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'parent_page_var' of null`**

I can also use jQuery if the it provides resolution, but I'll prefer Javascript.

**PS: Everything is there on same domain, so there is no CORS thing required. I just want a simple solution**

Here is the code for window.opener:

```
window.opener.parent_page_var = pop_up_variable_value;
```

Comment: Can we see the 'window.opener' code?

Comment: all variables will be under `window.parent` so you can access your variable with window.parent.my_variable

Comment: Here is the code for window.opener: **`window.opener.parent_page_var = pop_up_variable_value;`**

Comment: @Ahmad: _“all variables will be under `window.parent`”_ – no they won’t. (I)Frames have parents, popups don’t – popups have an `opener`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IN the child page:

```
window.opener.parent_page_var.value = document.child_form_name.field_name.value;
self.close();
```